# Multiple Google Analytics 4 script trackers for one page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-analytics-4

***Briefly:*** The main idea is that I have a website with integrated Google Analytics 4 (GA4) and an independent widget integrated into this website, that also has GA4. As the result, events are sent to both trackers. How I can isolate that from each other?

***Detailed:***
Have 2 react web apps. One is the *parent*-website and the other is integrated in it widget (made as react app that is built with Webpack into 2 files - js and css). This widget can be integrated to any website with script tag and css link. And this widget needs to have Google Analytics. But a *parent*-website can also have integrated Google Analytics.
If this *parent*-website has Universal Analytics, it is ok, sent events are isolated, but if both have new GA4 troubles have place.

I've tried to integrate GA to both [test] apps with the help of react-ga4 library. As the result, both tracker accounts getting all events sent from widget and parent-website.
And also tried to use in parent-website manually added script tag and in widget app react-ga4 library. Also all events go everywhere.
[Inspect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBYKU.png)

Then I've tried to add GA4 scripts manually and have two configs for two trackers. The same happens - all events go to both trackers.

The main question how to isolate events sending?

```html
        <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
        <script
          async
          src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=TRACKING_ID_1"
        ></script>
        <script>
          window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
          function gtag() {
            dataLayer.push(arguments);
          }
          gtag("js", new Date());
    
          gtag("config", "TRACKING_ID_1");
        </script>
    
        <!-- Global site tag 2 (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
        <script
          async
          src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=TRACKING_ID_2"
        ></script>
        <script>
          window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
          function gtag() {
            dataLayer.push(arguments);
          }
          gtag("js", new Date());
    
          gtag("config", "TRACKING_ID_2");
        </script>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you need to modify your gtag event code a bit.

Please take a took about [this docuemnt](https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/gtagjs/routing).

```
gtag('event', 'sign_in', { 'send_to': 'G-XXXXXX-2' });
```

The main idea is adding a parameter call `send_to` and ask the event only sent to the tracking id.

And if you need to config multiple tracking id.

You can just config second tracker

No need add the `<script>` again

```html
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=TRACKING_ID_1"></script>

<script>
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
function gtag() {
  dataLayer.push(arguments);
}
gtag("js", new Date());
gtag("config", "TRACKING_ID_1");
gtag("config", "TRACKING_ID_2");
</script>
```

Comment: thank you for your quick answer. trying it out.

Comment: Darrellwan, you are a life saver. thank you. I don't know how I've missed this send_to parameter in docs...
In result, I can pass it even using react-ga4 library, like this: 
`ReactGA4.event("event_name", { send_to: "TRAKING_ID" })`

Comment: No worry. Sometimes the document is not easy to find. Glad this work for you

Comment: gtag support groups as well. Please refer to 
https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/gtagjs/routing