# How to send an event via gtag to a specific gtag code in GA4 when using multiple gtag codes

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, google-analytics, google-analytics-4

In my project I am using two different gtag codes and sending my events to each of them (one for a client, and one for our own tracking). The problem is, because of this, each time an event is sent it registers as 2 events at once for each *separate* analytics report, despite the event only being sent once for each separate gtag code. Here is the script tag I'm importing in the head of my html:

```
    <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-CLIENT-GTAG"></script>
    <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-OUR-GTAG"></script>
    <script>
      window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
      function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
      gtag('js', new Date());
      gtag('config', 'G-CLIENT-GTAG');
      gtag('config', 'G-OUR-GTAG');
    </script>
```

Here's where we send the events to each gtag at the same time:

```
        analyticsService.sendGaEvent(
          this[$clientGtag],
          eventData,
          this.sku,
        );
        analyticsService.sendGaEvent(
          this[$ourGtag],
          eventData,
          this.sku,
        );
```

Then in our sendGaEvent function, we create our trackers and send the events:

```
public sendGaEvent(gTag: string, eventData: AnalyticsEvents, sku: string) 
{
     const ga4Instance = this[$analyticsMap].get(gTag);
     const ga4ProductData = this[$ga4AnalyticsUniqueEventMap].get(sku);
     const ga4Tracker = ga4Instance!.tracker;
     this[$ga4AnalyticsUniqueEventMap].set(gTag, eventData); 
     gtag('event', eventData.event_action,
     {
       'event_action': eventData.event_action,
       'event_category': eventData.event_category,
       'event_label': eventData.event_label,
       'value': eventData.value
     });
}
```

So even though it's sending it to a different gtag each time `analyticsService.sendGaEvent` is called, it still registers as 2 events on each analytics report. I believe this is somehow due to us calling `gtag('event',...)` once for each gtag code, but not explicitly passing in the gtag code to the `gtag('event',...)` function, so it may just be sending the events to every gtag code initialized in the script tag of our `<head>` by default. Is there some way to call `gtag('event',...)` using a *specific* gtag code only? Or some other way to work around this?

Comment: You can take a look at this answer. Just add the `send_to` parameter
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73483177/multiple-google-analytics-4-script-trackers-for-one-page/73483271#73483271

Comment: @Darrellwan Thank you! Unfortunately this still seems to have the same issue. I added the `'send_to': gTag` line directly above the `'event_action' line and am still getting two events sent to each gtag on analytics.

Comment: Actually nevermind, this did the trick. I had just implemented it incorrectly at first. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it help. I will see how to improve that answer that cause less misunderstanding

Comment: The answer was perfect! I just forgot to update my second gtag event function call. Is there a way on here to mark someone's comment as the answer?